# Trying to fscanf multiple values (3 strings + integer) in a single line

Tags: c, file, scanf

I need to scan 3 strings and an integer from an already existing file, and save them each as an element in an array of structures. The file is formatted as such:

string1  string2  integer  string3

string1  string2  integer  string3

... and so on.

when fscanf-ing for them, it correctly scans string1, the integer, and string3. However, string2 always appears to create an error when scanning it, and when any of the string2's are printed, they are either cut off short, or have some odd ASCII symbol, like a question mark in a box; it also sometimes triggers the system "bell" sound.

I've tested collecting the strings through fscanf for each different one, and it is only the second one that ever messes up.

A stripped-down version of my code, highlighting the issue

```
struct carinfo
{
    char name[10];
    char make[15];
    int number;
    char color[10];
 }car[4];

filepointer = fopen("file.txt", "r");

while(!feof(filepointer))
{
   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
   { 
       fscanf(filepointer, "%s %s %d %s", &car[i].name[10], 
      &car[i].make[15], &car[i].number, &car[i].color[10]);

       printf("%s\n", &car[i].make[15]);
   }
}
```

my expected result is that the second string will scan properly, and be stored in its entirety to its element in the array of structures; instead, the value is usually cut off (at around 2-3 characters instead of 15) and contain weird ASCII symbols.

Comment: `&struct[i].string1[10]` does not read ten characters into a buffer, it reads characters into the buffer **starting at the 11th character position**. If this is your intent, there's probably a better way of expressing it, as this code looks really strange. Can you show the declaration for your "struct". `struct` is a reserved keyword, so that can't compile in its current form.

Comment: The beeps and blorps you're hearing are probably uninitialized character buffer data which tends to be just random garbage, but unless you show a bit more code for context it's hard to say.

Comment: @tadman code has been updated to better represent my actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `fscanf()` function to this, will solve your issue.

***Code***

```
fscanf(filepointer, "%s %s %d %s", car[i].name, 
       car[i].make, &car[i].number, car[i].color);
```

You can find true way of using [fscanf()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fscanf.html) in [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/):

```
char str [80];
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","w+");
fscanf (pFile, "%s", str);
```

But as [chris-dodd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16406/chris-dodd) stated at comment section using `feof(filepointer)` inside `while` loop [not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong).

This code below i correct it by using `fscanf()` return value.

I obtain this way in a [stack overflow answer by lio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6000489/7508077)

## Complete version of your program

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct carinfo
{   
    char name[10];
    char make[15];
    int number;
    char color[10];
}car[4];


int main(){
    
int i=0;    
    
FILE* filepointer = fopen("file.txt", "r");

if(!filepointer){
    printf("can't open file\n");
}

int ret=0;

do {
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){      
        ret=fscanf(filepointer, "%s %s %d %s", &car[i].name, 
        &car[i].make, &car[i].number, &car[i].color);
        printf("%s\n", &car[i].make);
    }
} while (ret != EOF);

    return 0;
}
```

**file.txt**

```
salam beshoma 10 daram
kee innak 15 inomikhonid!
```

Comment: This didnt seem to work; after this, it saved the string as just 10 empty characters, and didnt actually save the characters from the file. I didnt have time to test it with the other strings as I'm heading to bed.

Comment: @TheyThinkThatImTomCruise No, Its put first string into the name char array and insert a `\0` at the end of it.

Comment: See [why is while(!feof always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: @ChrisDodd Ok, that's good capture, thank you, i read this before, I will correct that mistake.